# Function/Sub not Declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: vb.net, function, declaration

I'm pretty new with vb.net so I'm not completely familiar with how public functions are called from one form to another. When hovering over "myIniFile" and "initGPIB" in the class, frmReadTemp, I get the error message - not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level. However, that function and sub is Public in another class.

```
Public Class frmReadTemp


    Private Sub cmdRun_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdRun.Click
        Dim err_code As eCode = eCode.ERR_NONEr

        myInifile()
        err_code = initGPIB()

    End Sub

End Class


Public Class PowerSupply_setup

#Region "Variable Declarations"

    Dim myIniFile As IniFile
    Public instrInfo As New ArrayList
    Public myiniObj As iniObj
    WithEvents myPS As IPowerSupply
    WithEvents myTestSystem As New testSystemObj(4)

#End Region

    Public Sub loadIniFile()

        Dim tenable As String

        'Power Supply
        myiniObj.ps_addr.PrimaryAddress = myIniFile.GetInteger("GPIB_INSTRUMENTS", "POWERSUPPLY_ADDR", 6)
        myiniObj.ps_addr.ComInterface = 1
        myiniObj.ps_type = myIniFile.GetString("GPIB_INSTRUMENTS", "POWERSUPPLY_TYPE", "HP6632").ToUpper
        tenable = myIniFile.GetString("GPIB_INSTRUMENTS", "POWERSUPPLY_AVAILABLE", "NO")
        myiniObj.ps_available = IIf(tenable.ToUpper.Trim.StartsWith("NO"), False, True)
        'myiniObj.ps_available = IIf((myIniFile.GetString("GPIB_INSTRUMENTS", "POWERSUPPLY_AVAILABLE", 0)) = "0", False, True)
        myiniObj.ps_port = myIniFile.GetInteger("GPIB_INSTRUMENTS", "POWERSUPPLY_PORT", 1)
        myiniObj.ps_ov_offset = Val(myIniFile.GetInteger("GPIB_INSTRUMENTS", "POWERSUPPLY_OVERVOLTAGE_OFFSET", "3.0"))
        myiniObj.ps_current_limit = Val(myIniFile.GetInteger("GPIB_INSTRUMENTS", "POWERSUPPLY_CURRENT_LIMIT", "3.0"))

    End Sub

    Public Function initGPIB() As swiErr.eCode
        Dim err_code As eCode = eCode.ERR_NONE

        If (instrInfo.Count = 0) Then

            'init Power Supply
            If (err_code = eCode.ERR_NONE And myiniObj.ps_available) Then
                Dim iInfo2(1) As String
                If (myiniObj.ps_type.ToUpper.Contains("HP6632")) Then
                    myPS = New HP6632(myiniObj.ps_addr)
                    err_code = myPS.ErrCode
                ElseIf (myiniObj.ps_type.ToUpper.Contains("E3631")) Then
                    myPS = New E3631A(myiniObj.ps_addr)
                    err_code = myPS.ErrCode
                ElseIf (myiniObj.ps_type.ToUpper.Contains("E66311")) Then
                    myPS = New E66311B(myiniObj.ps_addr)
                    err_code = myPS.ErrCode
                ElseIf (myiniObj.ps_type.ToUpper.Contains("E66319")) Then
                    myPS = New E66311B(myiniObj.ps_addr)
                    err_code = myPS.ErrCode
                ElseIf (myiniObj.ps_type.ToUpper.Contains("SCPI")) Then
                    myPS = New SCPI_PS(myiniObj.ps_addr)
                    err_code = myPS.ErrCode
                Else
                    myPS = Nothing
                    err_code = eCode.ERR_INST_PS_NOT_SUPPORTED
                End If

                If (err_code = eCode.ERR_NONE) Then
                    iInfo2(0) = myPS.instrumentName
                    iInfo2(1) = myPS.gpibAddress.PrimaryAddress
                    myPS.selectPort = Me.myiniObj.ps_port
                    instrInfo.Add(iInfo2)
                    myPS.OverVoltageOffset = myiniObj.ps_ov_offset
                    myPS.setPwrOff()
                End If

                If (err_code = eCode.ERR_INST_GPIB_SEARCH) Then err_code = eCode.ERR_INST_MISSING_PWRSUPPLY
            Else
                'create object but set availability to false
                myPS = New E3631A()
            End If

            Me.myTestSystem.instrument.PS = myPS

        End If

        Return err_code
    End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable `myIniFile` and the method `initGPIB` are indeed public, so they are accessible from outside of the `PowerSupply_setup` class.  However, since they are members of that class, they must be referenced via an object of that class.  For instance:

```
Dim mySetup As New PowerSupply_setup()
err_code = mySetup.initGPIB()
```

Since they are instance members (not `Shared`), you must create an instance (an object) of the class and then you can access them via that object.  If you create multiple objects of the class, then you will have multiple copies of the members.

If you only ever need one copy of the members, and you don't want to have to create an object just to use them, you can alternatively decare them as `Shared` members of the class:

```
Public Class PowerSupply_setup
    Public Shared Sub loadIniFile()
        ' ...
    End Sub
    ' ...
End Class
```

Then you can access them directly via the class name:

```
err_code = PowerSupply_setup.initGPIB()
```

Personally, I would recommend against doing so, unless really necessary, because it leads to global state which can be dangerous.  If you really do want to go down that road, though, and you don't even want to have to use the class name to access those members, you could also put them in a `Module` rather than in a class.

Answer (score 1):

Couple different things going on here:

1. Dim is private, not public, so you'll need to declare the var Public or make a Public Property to access it.
2. Any property/method not declared Shared must be called from an instance member.  In other words, you actually have to create a Powersupply_Setup object and call Init_GPIB() from that copy, unless you change the declaration of Init_GIPB().